# Escaping from the $.ajax({ success: function() }) dungeon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I have a common scenario where everything depends on AJAX responses, followed by possibly more AJAX responses.

What ends up happening is lots and lots of presentation (page-specific) code gets thrown inside the **success()** callback:

```
 $.ajax({
     ...
     success: function (response) {
         // too much $('#something').html() crap goes in here!
     }
 });
```

What is the best practice for removing this "data access" code completely from the presentation code but maintaining the loading sequence?

I've used deferred calls like `$.when().then()` but that still seems sloppy to me.  Is there anything better?

To make an answer even simpler, let's say I want to retrieve information about a `Person` object and segregate all that logic into its own area.  Example:

*note: this code will not work - I am aware of that*

**Person.js:**

```
var Person = {
    getByID: function(id) {
        // ajax call to return a person object (format is arbitrary)
        //   { id: 12345, name: 'Joe Smith', email: 'joe@smith.com }
    }
};
```

**SomePage.html**

```
var myID = 12345;  // get ID from wherever
var person = Person.getByID(myID);
$('#person .name').html(person.name);
$('#person .email').html(person.email);
```

---

**EDIT: My solution**

Although many of the answers were helpful, I chose to pass callback functions that separate all the various pieces of logic from each other.  Example code:

**JS:**

```
Person = {
    get: function(params, callback) {
         $.ajax({
            url: '/person/get',
            data: params,
            success: callback
         });
    }
};

Pages = {
    Person: {
        render: function(person) {
           // in reality I'm using templates, this is for simplicity
           $('#person .name').html(person.name);
           $('#person .email').html(person.email);
        }
    }
};
```

**SomePage.html**

```
$('#someElement').someEvent(function() {
    var params = {
        id: 12345
    };

    Person.get(params, Pages.Person.render);
}
```

I should also add I found this slide deck extremely informative:

http://speakerdeck.com/u/addyosmani/p/large-scale-javascript-application-architecture

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: I'm still learning it, but it would appear that backbone.js addresses alot of this.

Comment: @SLaks I know it's not possible to completely separate them which is why I put the italic note above my theoretical code example.  I'm looking for a constructive answer on best practices or methodologies to separate them as much as possible.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://zef.me/3715/three-routes-to-spaghetti-free-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now know the correct answer is:

> There are over 9000 libraries created specifically for this, a common problem known as AMD.

*-TerryR*

http://speakerdeck.com/u/addyosmani/p/large-scale-javascript-application-architecture

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to have something in the success callback, but you don't need presentation details there.  The success call could simply call:

```
Person.render(attributes, element)
```

And the details would be in the render function.

Answer (score 3):

As SLaks says, what you want to do is impossible in the asynchronous context of AJAX.

However, nothing speaks against keeping the majority of the code in separate objects that do all the grunt work. You would then call those objects and their methods from your success callbacks and pass them all the necessary data. That would ensure that your callbacks contain only the bare minimum of code.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me that you may wish to introduce the [Model-View-Controller design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) into your application.  In the simplest form the `Model` would be responsible for fetching the required data which is then passed through to the `View` to be rendered; the `Controller`'s job is to process incoming requests, invoke the `Model` and shuffle the data into the `View` in the expected format.

As others have mentioned there are plenty of [lightweight MVC frameworks](http://microjs.com/) out there for JavaScript; but you should be able get the basic concept up and running just by using jQuery and a templating engine (such as [Mustache.js](http://mustache.github.com/)) so you can get some separation between Model (fetching the data and building a common object graph) and View (rendering a template and adding the rendered HTML to the DOM).

As for you proposed Person example, you could make use of [jQuery's Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) to allow `Person.getById` to return a Promise, eg:

```
var Person = {
    getByID: function(id) {
        var result;

        // Return a Promise which we will resolve once the AJAX call completes.
        return $.Deferred(function (dfd) { 
            $.ajax(...)
                .done(function (response) { 
                    // Parse the AJAX response into your app's model data.
                    result = { 
                        id: response.id, 
                        name: response.firstName,
                        email: response.email
                    };

                    // Resolve the Promise and supply the Person object.
                    dfd.resolve(person);
                });
        }).promise();
    }
};
```

Your `Controller` can then invoke the `Model` and then supply the result to the `View` (this is where you could make use of templates).

```
Person.getByID(myID)
    .done(function(person) { 
        $('#person .name').html(person.name);
        $('#person .email').html(person.email);
    });
```

Comment: My application is already MVC, on the server side.  All of the AJAX calls are to `/controller/action/[object]`.  Client MVC on top of server MVC sounds messy...

Comment: As a front-end developer I would disagree with your statement.  The server side and client side are totally separate domains which should be decoupled from each other.

Comment: You know what's messier than MVC on top of MVC?  Spaghetti on top of MVC.  The question is whether you have enough client code that it merits more formal organization.

Comment: @JonnyReeves I have nothing against MVC on MVC, would love to see a simple example...

Answer (score 1):

You can slightly change your example to make it work asynchronously - still cleaner code than shoving everything in to the success callback function:

```
var myID = 12345;  // get ID from wherever
Person.getByID(myID, function(person) {
    $('#person .name').html(person.name);
    $('#person .email').html(person.email);
});
```